# Put information from mySQL into a Fragment textView's before onCreate

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-fragments

My application currently loads the fragment and when I try to load the profile of the person during the fragments onCreate(), it ends up pulling after the fragment is made and none of my textviews can change.

Log:

> 04-30 23:03:37.522    5495-5495/uconn.campusoddjobs D/I'm in the Fragment﹕ null
>   04-30 23:03:37.772    5495-5908/uconn.campusoddjobs D/Pulled From mySQL﹕ test

Code:

```
public class MyAccountFragment extends Fragment{
private TextView name;
private static final String PROFILE_URL = "http://campusoddjobs.com/oddjobs/buildprofile.php";
private Profile profile = new Profile();
private String test = String.valueOf(profile.username());
View rootview;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_account_layout, container, false);
    Log.d("I'm in the Fragment", test);
    name = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.nameview);
    name.setText("you don't change"); //the textView changes to this though.
    return rootview;
  }
 }
```

Should I be initializing their profile before the fragment?  If so where?

Edit:
Code that pulls data:

```
public class Profile extends Activity{

private int id;
private String email;
private String username;
private String bio;
private String posted_jobs;
private String accepted_jobs;
private int karma;

public String getTest;

private static final String PROFILE_URL = "http://campusoddjobs.com/oddjobs/buildprofile.php";
JSONparser jparser = new JSONparser();

public Profile() {

    email = getEmailFromMemory();
    new buildProfile().execute();
 }

// ---------- Getters ----------

public String username(){return username;}
 ---------------------------
// ---------- Setters ----------
public void setUsername(String u){username = u;}
// -----------------------------

private String getEmailFromMemory() {          // pulls email from shared preferences
    Context context = MainActivity.getAppContext();
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("user_settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String extractedText = prefs.getString("email", "error: no email");
    return extractedText;
}

class buildProfile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public Profile getProfile()
    {
        return Profile.this;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));

            JSONObject json = jparser.makeHttpRequest(PROFILE_URL, "GET", params);

            Profile.this.setUsername(json.getString("username"));
            Log.d("Pulled From mySQL", username());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you pulling your data from ? If it's http call then naturally there will be a race between the result and the creation of your fragment. You should post the whole code including the one that calls that url.

Comment: I am pulling from an http call, that uses PHP to get mySQL information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, there is a race going on between the http call and fragment creation. So to solve it simply make one starts after another. You have two options:
- instantiate the fragment after you receive a response from http request
- create the fragment first. Once it's created, trigger a callback to the activity that sends a http request. Upon its completion update the fragment.

Which one you choose should depend on the design of the app. Any long process such as http call requires interim interaction so your user will know the app isn't crashing (i.e run a spinner, animation, or do it in background)

This is for the first approach. I am assuming this AsyncTask is executed in a *legitimate* way (through Activity lifecycle methods not constructor as the question suggested).

```
class buildProfile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
  ...

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    try {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));

        JSONObject json = jparser.makeHttpRequest(PROFILE_URL, "GET", params);

        String username = json.getString("username");
        Profile.this.setUsername(username);
        return username;

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
      super.onPostExecute(s);
      if (s == null){return;}
      //this is where MyAccountFragment is created
      getFragmentManager()
      .beginTransaction()
      .add(R.id.myaccountfragmentcontainer, MyAccountFragment .newInstance(s))
      .commit();

  }
}
```

MyAccountFragment

```
public class MyAccountFragment extends Fragment{
...
private TextView name;

  public static MyAccountFragment newInstance(String username) {
    MyAccountFragment f = new MyAccountFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("username", username);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
  }

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_account_layout, container, false);

    name = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.nameview);

    // take username argument and put it in textview
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    String username = args.getString("username");
    name.setText(username); 

    return rootview;
  }
}
```